# Auto Value change in jsp value

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am developing an application on jsp. I need to change content of HTML table in jsp page for  every x seconds.

I am done with all the other functionalities except this one.

Can someone provide some help on this.

Here is my code

**Auto.jsp**

```
 <div class="push">
<%
int a=10;
int b=20;
int c=30;
%>

</div>
```

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var count=0;
 function change(){
    $('.change').text(count++)..load('Auto.jsp').fadeIn("slow");;
    setTimeout(change,10000);
}
$('.change').click(function() 
    change();
});

 <div class="change" style="background-color: green">Change</div>
```

Comment: use either javascript or jquery timers

Comment: Don't you think some more info in necessary.

Comment: Thanks but  could u write  me some code

Comment: @Deepak Tiwari  what information u need i will provide u

Comment: Part of HTML you wanna change.

Comment: @Deepak Tiwari yes i want to change div section on every x sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Ex**: HTML Code

```
<div class="change">Change This</div>
```

**JQuery Code:**

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var count=0;
     function change(){
        $('.change').text(count++);
        setTimeout(change,1000);
    }

   change();

});
```

Div will change in every *1000ms*.

Comment: but how div will take new content in every x sec and old  content will be  visible

Comment: Can you give an example what you really want? In my code there is count var which will be incremented in every 1 sec.

Comment: i want that div  area auto refresh  as u did but  every time it should display new content and old invisible

Comment: i edited my post little  where 3 java varible i want all that varilabe display one by one

Comment: if you run my code then you will see that it hides the old div text and displays new one.

Comment: i edited my post   that how i am using   ur code please check i  is there any thing wrong tell me please

Comment: auto.jsp is my jsp page

Comment: Why are you loading jsp page in jquery?